# How do I fix - "CUDA error : Launch failed in cuCtxSynchronize()" and "cuCtxCreate: Launch failed" in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I'm using 2.78 cycles with experimental and it have been stable until recent when this errors started.

[image]

I haven't started to work with the scene, the only thing I have don is setting up the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did update my driver for my GTX660 to version 373.06. The only problem is that blender do have stability issues now but GPU rending do work.