# CUDA error: Launch failed in cuCtxSynchronize(), line 1372

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

I have the following CUDA error when trying to render my project in cycles:

```
CUDA error: Launch failed in cuCtxSynchronize(), line 1372
```

My scene rendered well some days ago. After adding new elements and models the error appeared. I had this error already some time ago, while working on this project, but after changing the content and sample amount in the render settings it disappeared until today.

I am using a **GeForce 1080 Ti with 11 GBytes of Ram**. The scene use currently not much vram of my graphic card. So the vram can not be the reason.

Any ideas for a solution please? Maybe some developers are reading this too.

Thank you a lot for any tips

Chris

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/rendering-with-gpu-crashed and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64615/how-do-i-fix-cuda-error-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize-and-cuctxcrea and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cuCtxSynchronize

Comment: Thank you for the links. I have already seeked for a solution here in the forums, but the main problems of other users are based on low memory. As I wrote my card has 11 GBytes of Ram so mem can not be the problem.

Especially because the scene rendered already and there were some errors too before I started to add new elements.

I am using the Principled shader for nearly all materials. I guess I will replace the shader to the regular shader model and see what happen then. The new shader could be a reason too.

Do someone has any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: https://support.allegorithmic.com/documentation/display/SPDOC/GPU+drivers+crash+with+long+computations and http://developer.download.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Timeout_Detection_Recovery.htm and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/tdr-registry-keys

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this problem for months. Used different computers, re-installed Blender, re-installed windows (I am using 8.1 & 10), installed new and old drivers for my Nvidia card, changed the TDR and everything I could think of...but no luck.

Then it occurred to me that the Gforce Experience runs in the background (and being in my opinion, not a well written program) may be overlapping the memory of Blender or at least hogging the memory. So I un-installed it and magic!!! All Cuda errors and memory errors went away. **Blender works again as it should!!!**

I hope this works for you, as it did for me. Unfortunately, I did not discover this for months, until I had pulled every single strand of hair out of my head.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is interesting. I have not tried your solution yet but there is an article I have written to solve the issue even if you have GForce Experience running and don't want to uninstall it.

Here ist the link to my article: http://www.christoph-werner.de/2017/12/31/blender-fix-for-cycles-bug-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize/

I forgot to mention it here.

Comment: Thank You for your reply' I can see that you are very experienced and that was a nice link to your report. For me, the TDR changes did not solve it. If I re-install "The Experience" The issue returns. Since Blender is more important to me and I can do manual driver updates, I choose to keep a functioning Blender.

Comment: Have you tried higher TDR values like I mention it in my article to increase the waiting time? Sometimes 30 seconds are far not enough. Greetings.