# Render error with Cycles using GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

I am new to Blender so forgive me if I am missing something obvious, but here is my problem : everytime I try to render a scene with Cycles and GPU Compute, it crashes after a few seconds, even with the default General new scene (just a cube). I usually get an error message like this one :

```
Error: CUDA error: Hardware stack error in cuCtxSynchronize(), line 1862
```

Or this one :

```
Error: CUDA error: illegal address in cuCtxSynchronize(), line 1862
```

I am running on Windows 10 with :

- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 (latest driver v446.14)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50Ghz
- 8 GB RAM

I tried to reinstall Blender (using v2.83), reinstall my graphic card driver, but nothing does the job so far. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try posting this on https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Uninstall "Nvidia Gforce" experience: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96878/cuda-error-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize-line-1372 or edit the registry.  http://artificialflight.org/blog/2013/cycles-crash-cuda-tdr-error/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CUDA ERROR: Launch failed in cuCtxSynchronize()” and “cuCtxCreate: Launch failed” when Rendering in Cycles using GPU](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102536/cuda-error-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize-and-cuctxcreate-launch-failed)

Comment: I still got the "hardware stack error" after uninstalling Gforce experience, unfortunately.